# configure mod_rewrite to allow img, js and css files?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

in my .htaccess i've got these lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

i tried to include js files with this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="system/application/media/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

but it doesnt work since the rules dont let it pass. it works when i turn the rewrite engine off.

how can i change the rules so it allows url with a /js, /css and /img?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At another RewriteCond after your first one that will prevent your RewriteRule from matching.  I sometimes filter on specific file extensions for static content files using the following rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html|swf|mp3|wav|txt)$
```

If you want to do it based on directory, then you'll want something more like this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(css|js|img)/
```

Put one of those before your existing `RewriteCond` and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks! it worked great! i find all these rules so cryptic. good to have it working right away so i can give it some time later to understand them.